# Django: When passing a string with -,anything behind - get droped

Tags: django, url, django-2.1

I try to pass a string param on django,but when I try it,anything behind - get droped.

I'm using Django 2.1.7 on Python3.My OS is Mac OS Mojave 10.14.

I'm accessing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ruleset/a096abd9-3855-4a91-9336-1d7e66aa5323`

```
def ruleSet(request,id_):
    return HttpResponse(id_)
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'ruleset/(\w+)', view.ruleSet)
]
```

I except to get `a096abd9-3855-4a91-9336-1d7e66aa5323`

I got `a096abd9` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is happening because "\w" didn't match "-" char.

You need to write regex which can match uuid.

Try below

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ruleset/<str:id_>', view.ruleSet)
]
```

Check below document for info about the pattern in Django URLs
https://www.webforefront.com/django/regexpdjangourls.html

Comment: Thanks you very much!